# How do I embed an Adobe Flash (.swf) file in Excel or Word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, flash

How do I embed an Adobe Flash (`.swf`) file in Microsoft Excel or Word?

Comment: HI Rich, I asked this as I have seen people fooling email filters which removes swf files by embedding them in excel/work. I was just curious to know how they do that? Any 3rd party tools used?

Answer (score 5):

Using *Office XP*, Excel or Word

From the **'View'** menu select **'Toolbars'** and tick the **'Control Toolbox'**

On the **'Control Toolbox'** toolbar click on the **'More controls'** icon

A list of controls will be displayed.  Scroll down until you find the **'Shockwave Flash Object'** and then click on it.

---

*Excel*

This should change your cursor to a crosshair.  Move to the area on the worksheet where you want to inset the **'Shockwave Flash Object'**.
Left click, hold and drag to create a box of the required size.

*Word*

Word will automatically insert the control where the cursor is.
It's size can be set by dragging the edges or via it's **'Properties'**

---

Next right click on the control you have just inserted and select **'Properties'**.

Set the following properties

- Autoload = True
- EmbedMovie = True
- Enabled  = True
- Loop = True
- Playing = True
- Visible = True
- Movie = c:\flash.swf (Change this to the location of your .swf file)

Close the **'Properties'** control

Save the file.

Close the file.

Reopen the file.

The .swf file should start playing automatically.

Comment: Works with every OLE object.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 2007 (in previous versions I guess it's pretty much the same):

"Insert" tab > Object > Flash Document

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, when I tried it, that the swf object displays well enough for me - save, re-open, display.

The swf file in my docx was on my C:\, I right-clicked the swf object > properties > "Movie" : "Full_File_Path.swf". As above, I found that 'EmbedMovie' and 'Enabled' options weren't available in my version of Word 2007 (standard issue, legit version), though 'Embed' is, I toggled it to 'true'.

Therefore, when I sent the docx file around the office - nothing showed up! (shaaaame)

So, following on from this question, is there a way to actually embed the file for those who don't have access to my C:\?

I tried dropping the .swf file on our shared work network, and that dutifully showed up and wowed people - but what if the network's down, or someone is out of the office...

Just curious I suppose, but it's a neat trick so far!

[EDIT] Not sure if this is sane or not, but when I went to re-try the above, I now see that 'EmbedMovie' *IS* available, but 'Embed' is not, 'Enabled' is still unavailable.

[2nd EDIT] Ok, after a bit more testing, I found that switching back to DOC to embed the swf did so correctly. As a side-effect, the swf stuck on 'first frame' (mostly scripted swf though, so 'first frame' might be inaccurate). I had a few other people try to open my iterative tests:

User 1: 'DOC embedded swf' - displays an 'image', or possibly the swf stuck on frame 1, if swf not available from the file path used during creation.

User 2: 'DOC embedded swf' - displays and runs all scripts if swf available from file path used during creation (in our case a shared drive, a URL like youtube video would cut the mustard, too).

User 3: 'DOCX embedded swf' - displays blank box if swf not available from the file path used during creation (like a shared drive versus C:)

User 4: 'DOCX embedded swf' - displays and runs all scripts if swf available from file path used during creation.

Hope this helps someone/anyone!